# Error loading CSV to table

Tags: database, csv, hadoop, hive, rdbms

My CSV file contains details about employees of company. One column contains salary of employees (eg- $4,000).
So when I write a script to load data into a table by ',' delimited it takes my salary column as 4 & 000 seperately. How to deal with that ?

CSV File example -
Australia,35-39,Consulting,Start Up (1-25),Web Application Developer,"$10,001 - $25,000",Enterprise

Table code-

> create table survey
>   (
>   country string,
>   age string,
>   industryType string,
>   companyType string,
>   occupation string,
>   salary string,
>   project string)
>   row format delimited
>   fields terminated by ',' ;

Comment: Show us your sql statement please.

Comment: @aendeerei added table code. Could it be due to using String for salary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### References:

Conform to Apache's DDL syntax for [Create/Drop/Truncate Table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable), and, more specifically, to [Row Formats & SerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormats&SerDe), in order to change the `FIELDS/LINES/etc` properties, you can use:

- the **native SerDe** (if `ROW FORMAT` is not specified, or `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED` is set), or
- a **custom SerDe** (by applying the `SERDE` clause).

#### Option 1: Using the native Serde

```
CREATE TABLE survey(country string, age string, industryType string, companyType string, occupation string, salary string, project string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
    FIELDS 
        TERMINATED BY "," 
        ESCAPED BY "\\"
    LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Notice the lack of a clause which could specify the character to quote the field values.

#### Option 2: Using the custom Serde

See the record named "CSV/TSV" in the table from [Row Formats & SerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormats&SerDe).

```
CREATE TABLE survey(country string, age string, industryType string, companyType string, occupation string, salary string, project string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "separatorChar" = ",",
    "quoteChar"     = "\"",
    "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)     
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

I suggest you to make a test with a CSV file containing one line of values. Inside the line enclose all column values into double quotes and see what happens. Beeing enclosed, the "," character (like the one in `salary` field) will/should be automatically escaped and, therefore, saved as part of the corresponding column value.

Good luck.

Comment: Salary column got converted into double quotes automatically on converting excel-csv. Editing salary column will not be feasible as the file have such info of across 2000+ users and 10+ such files.

Comment: getting some errors while trying it. Edited in the question.

Comment: Show the line `ROW FORMAT SERDE...`. And which Hive version are you using?

Comment: `ROW FORMAT 
SERDE 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
    "seperatorChar" = ",",
    "quoteChar" = "\"",
    "escapeChar" = "\\"
    )
STORED AS TEXTFILE; `

HIVE VERSIOn - 1.1.0

Comment: I put the serde string that you now have in my first version of my answer! It was wrong, so I reedited it on 8. november already. E.g. I passed the correct Apache serde. Please read my answer again and take the current `ROW FORMAT SERDE ...` from it. Also, you made a mistake: it should be `separatorChar` not `seperatorChar`.